# Convert text list of urls into clickable HTML links

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to convert a text list of urls into clickable links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>  
<script>

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/

%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}

var a1 = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
var a2 = replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(a1);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a2;

</script>

<div id="test">
http://www.site.com/
http://www.site2.com/
http://www.site3.com/
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Firebug returns the list of sites in the console for:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
```

ie:
    www.site.com/  
    www.site2.com/ 
    www.site3.com/

**Why do I get this error for the line below?**

```
var a1 = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
```

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you're trying to scrub URLs you might consider using PHP's DOMDocument, instead of JavaScript. Personally, I rarely see links on a page, that are not actual links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are trying to access the element before it has been added so `document.getElementById('test')` return null. You can wrap it under `window.onload` or add the script after the html element.

Try:

```
<script>

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/

%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}

window.onload = function(){
  var elm =  document.getElementById("test");
  var modifiedHtml = replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(elm.innerHTML);
  elm.innerHTML = modifiedHtml ;
}

</script>
```